# Marshal struct and pointer in struct from c# to c++

Tags: c#, c++, c++14, marshalling

I have the following structures in C# and C++.

**C++**:

```cpp
typedef struct _st_a {
    double dLon;
    double dLat;
    double dE;
    double dN;
    double dU;
} ST_A;

typedef struct _st_b {
    unsigned short  usNumName;
    unsigned short  usNumType;
    double dRating;
    char* pTypes[8];
    char16_t sName[50];
    ST_A stPoi;

    _st_b() {
        std::memset(sNamePlace, 0, sizeof(sNamePlace));
    }
} ST_B;

typedef struct _st_c {
    unsigned short  usNumObtained;
    unsigned short  usStatus;
    ST_B     pPoiInfo[GAPI_MAX_POI_NUM];
} ST_C;
```

**C#**:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ST_A
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    public double dLon;                 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    public double dLat;       
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    public double dE;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    public double dN;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    public double dU;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ST_B
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public ushort usNumName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public ushort usNumType;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    public double dRating;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Define.GAPI_MAX_TYPE)]
    public IntPtr[] pTypes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = Define.GAPI_MAX_LENGTH_NAME)]
    public string sName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public ST_A stPoi;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ST_C
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public ushort usNumPlaceObtained;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public ushort usResStatus;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Define.GAPI_MAX_POI_NUM)]
    public ST_B[] pPoiInfo;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with the marshaling data above? When I use it, the returned data does not match the data on C++.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong? and I want to release `pTypes`, what should I do? know that it is allocated with `new` on the C++ side.

**Update1**: I tried writing a small function to test marshalling for struct ST_B. However, stPoi does not receive the result from the c++ side and the text string of pTypes is also incorrect

**C++**:

```cpp
void test_get_poi_info(ST_B &poi)
{
    poi.dRating = 5.6;
    poi.usNumType = 2;

    poi.pTypesInfo[0] = new char[6];
    poi.pTypesInfo[1] = new char[6];

    memset(poi.pTypes[0], 0, 6*sizeof(char));
    memset(poi.pTypes[1], 0, 6 * sizeof(char));

    memcpy(poi.pTypes[0], "hello", 5 * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(poi.pTypes[1], "klkll", 5 * sizeof(char));

    poi.usNumName = 3;

    memset(&poi.sName[0], 0, 50 * sizeof(char16_t));
    memcpy(&poi.sName[0], "鶴屋八", 3 * sizeof(char16_t));

    poi.stPoi.dE = 12.345;
    poi.stPoi.dN = 145.345;
    poi.stPoi.dU = 1.23;
    poi.stPoi.dLat = -123.2;
    poi.stPoi.dLon = 123.2;
}
```

I don't understand what's really going on.
Can someone help me?

**Update2**: I got the `pTypes` information using `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()`. Looks like I'm using the wrong way to get information.
However, I still have trouble with `stPoi`, I have retrieved all the remaining data except `stPoi`. I have tried many ways but it doesn't work? Is the problem due to struct `ST_B`? (e.g. order of member struct)

Comment: Remove the `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]`. `know that it is allocated with new on the C++ side` - then you can't release it.

Comment: @GSerg so is it any memory problem on the C# or C++ side of `pTypes`?

Comment: There isn't on either. You just can't release the pointers you receive.

Comment: I tried the above way. I print the data on the c++ side and it's exactly as expected. However, when tested on c#, it is completely different. I don't know what happened?

Comment: You don't need all of those `MarshalAs` attributes by the way. Eg you don't need to specify that a `double` must be marshalled as a `double`, that's the default anyway.

Comment: You need to specify the charset `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] public struct ST_B`. And you need to pass in the `pTypes` pointers from C# (and C++ would need to know how big the buffer is), so you should declare them as `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Define.GAPI_MAX_TYPE)] public StringBuilder[] pTypes;` and then initialize it with the correct number of stringbuilders and the correct capacity.

Comment: The sNamePlace member somehow disappeared from the declarations.  A missing member throws off the data of the subsequent struct members.